# Configure ActiveMQ to add queue in-memory instead of disk

Tags: linux, activemq-classic

Can ActiveMQ add queue in-memory instead of disk, and if yes what is the configuration to do so.

This is the my activemq.xml and the ActiveMQ version is 5.14.3 .

I need to know What exactly should I configure here or in any other configuration files for queues to be in-memory instead of disk.

Also I need to increase the Ram which the ActiveMQ start with to be 2GB of Ram

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

   <!-- Allows accessing the server log -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

Comment: Next time, I would suggest to add more details to your question, such as the exact version of ActiveMQ you are using and maybe tell us what did you try and the outcome. Spending some time reading the doc or reasearching this forum for similar questions would help too.

Comment: I have done B. Disable persistence in activemq.xml (you also need to comment or remove the persistenceAdapter element):

Comment: what about A is this mandatory or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can and there are a couple of ways to do it:

A. Set the NON_PERSISTENT message delivery flag on your MessageProducer or directly on the send operation:

```java
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
```

B. Disable persistence in activemq.xml (you also need to comment or remove the persistenceAdapter element):

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" persistent="false">
  <!--
  <persistenceAdapter>
    <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
  </persistenceAdapter>
  -->
</broker>
```

Comment: I have done B. Disable persistence in activemq.xml (you also need to comment or remove the persistenceAdapter element)

Comment: what about A. Set the NON_PERSISTENT message delivery flag on your MessageProducer or directly on the send operation   is that mandatory ??

Comment: also i need to increase the ram size of the activemq what do i have to do

Comment: Once you use B, there is no need to also use A. All messages sent to this broker won't be persistent. For the other question, you need to set [memoryUsage limit](https://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html#system-usage).

Comment: for memory limit in config i have <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" /> so do i have to replace this or leave and add <memoryUsage limit="2048 mb" />

Comment: you have to replace it

Comment: ● activemq.service - Apache ActiveMQ
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/activemq.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-02-12 22:07:03 PKT; 22min ago
  Process: 15932 ExecStart=/opt/activemq/bin/activemq start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15976 (java)
    Tasks: 58 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 275.9M
      CPU: 11.655s
   CGroup: /system.slice/activemq.service
           └─15976 /usr/bin/java -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties

Comment: after i replace the memory in the service is still 1GB

Comment: You also need to setthe initial and max JVM memory allocation pool. To do this, open the `bin/env` file with a text editor and change the existing values to `ACTIVEMQ_OPTS_MEMORY="-Xms2G -Xmx2G"`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support